# divide rect into horizontal parts and discard the first part

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a rect object , I want to

1. divide it into three horizontal parts
2. extracting the first horizontal part
3. retain the other two parts and display them .

   ```
     Rect Roi=faces[i];

     Roi.height = Roi.width / 3;

     Mat rect_region = frame(Roi);
   ```

I don't know how to proceed further with this , and I think the above code is not right .

Comment: Maybe Roi.y += Roi.height/3; Roi.height -= Roi.height/3;

Comment: how then I discard the first part and retain the other two parts ?

Comment: Mat rect_region = frame(Roi);

Comment: I will try it and update this post

Comment: Thanks @sturkmen it works fine , but sometimes not  , can you give me a hint of how you find this solution ?

Comment: @joe When it's not working fine, how is it not working fine? Does it still keep the first part? Or is something else the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like below

```
Rect Roi=faces[i]; 
// maybe you must to check here if( Roi.width > 0 & Roi.height > 0 ) 
Roi.y += Roi.height/3; 
Roi.height -= (Roi.height/3);
Mat rect_region = frame(Roi);
```